# How to package python program with its depdent packages?

Tags: python, package

I want to package my Python program with its dependent packages and deploy it. The reason why I also want to include its dependencies is that the target machine may have another version of the dependent library, and I want to use a specific version. I am not sure whether python has dependency management tool. I think dependency management tool like maven of java is what I want.

Comment: check out the [pip-bundle](https://github.com/develersrl/pip-bundle), also http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/27/python-on-wheels/

Answer (score 1):

### Make it pip-installable

There is [extensive documentation](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) on how to create a [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/)-instable package.

The main thing is to write  a `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my_package_name',
      version='0.1',
      description='It solves all your problems',
      url='http:solves.it',
      author='Me',
      author_email='me@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['my_package_name'],
      install_requires=[
          'flask',
          'another_package'
      ],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Here `install_requires` contains the [list of dependencies](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dependencies.html). You can also use a an [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file to list all the dependencies with version number.

You can create such file with:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Than you can re-create the same environment with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

### Make it standalone

Probably the most powerful, cross-platform library for this is [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). It works for Python 2 and 3 alike, allows to distribute your program as a single executable file or a single directory, and supports many commonly used Python libraries.

Comment: This might not be what I prefer, this need to build when any code change. I am not sure whether python has dependency management tool like maven in java. I think dependency management tool like maven is what I want.